# Sorting data from several files gives unreadable output?

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding

I have a set of 100 .txt files with transcribed Japanese conversation data encoded in EUC-JP. The filenames all begin with 'data'. I want to make a program that sorts the sentences into two different files, based on whether the speaker is male or female. Every line begins with M or F plus a 3 digit speaker code. This is my code for reading the files:

```
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.startswith("data") and i.endswith(".txt"):
        with codecs.open(i,'r',encoding='EUC-JP') as f:
            text = f.read()
```

Sometimes a speakers utterances will continue over several lines, and so the line does not start with a speaker code. To get around this I assign a current speaker with the code below

```
male_speaker_utterances = []
female_speaker_utterances = []
current_speaker = ' '
for l in text:
    if l.startswith("F"): 
        female_speaker_utterances.append(l)
        current_speaker = 'F'
    elif l.startswith("M"):
        male_speaker_utterances.append(l)
        current_speaker = 'M'
    else:
        if current_speaker == 'F':
            female_speaker_utterances.append(l)
        elif current_speaker == 'M':
            male_speaker_utterances.append(l)
```

Finally I write the data to files:

```
fem = codecs.open("female_data.txt",'w',encoding='EUC-JP')
mal = codecs.open("male_data.txt",'w',encoding='EUC-JP')
fem.write(female_speaker_utterances)
mal.write(male_speaker_utterances)
```

My problem is the output format I get. When I read the file as a EUC-JP, it just gives me a bunch of character codes, like these:

```
[u'F', u'1', u'3', u'5', u'\uff1a', u'\u5973', u'\u6027', u'\uff12', u'\uff10', u'\u4ee3', u'\u5f8c', u'\u534a', u'\u3001', u'\u5317', u'\u6d77', u'\u9053', u'\u672d', u'\u5e4c', u'\u5e02', u'\u51fa', u'\u8eab', u'\u3001', u'\u540c', u'\u5e02', u'\u5728', u'\u4f4f', u'\r', u'\n', u'\uff20', u'\u53c2', u'\u52a0', u'\u8005', u'\u306e', u'\u95a2', u'\u4fc2', u'\uff1a', u'\u5927', u'\u5b66', u'\u9662', u'\u306e', u'\u540c', u'\u7d1a', u'\u751f', u'\r', u'\n'
```

I'd like to get some readable text instead. Could it be a problem with writing the list to a file? I'm not sure how I can work around that. I've tried converting it to a string with str(female_speaker_utterances) before writing it to the new files, but that gives me the same unreadable output. 
I'm very new at python and programming in general, and this is my first post on here. I'm using Python 2.7.6. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is split the text into two separate files; its a lot quicker to just write it out as you read it in.

You can use `glob` to easily filter out the relevant files:

```
import glob
import codecs

with codecs.open('female.txt', 'w', encoding='EUC-JP') as female,
     codecs.open('male.txt', 'w', encoding='EUC-JP') as male:
         for filename in glob.iglob('/some/directory/data*.txt'):
             with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='EUC-JP') as the_file:
                 for line in the_file:
                     # The first letter of each line is either M or F
                     # The next 3 digits are the speaker code
                     if line[0] == 'M':
                         male.write(line)
                     if line[0] == 'F':
                         female.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When  I try to run the program it gives me an "Invalid syntax" error, because of the comma at the end of the line: "with codecs.open('female.txt', 'w', encoding='EUC-JP') as female,". Any ideas? 
Also, I'm not sure how I will include the lines that do not start with a speaker code. I was a bit ambiguous perhaps, but most lines start with M or F, and then that person's utterance can continue over 3 lines, without those lines being marked M or F. With your suggestion, those lines would not be included, right? Again, thanks!

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Ah I see - if not all lines are marked correctly then those non-marked lines will be skipped. However you have already solved that problem :)

Comment: Python 2.7.6. I'll just edit that into the original question.
Yes, that problem should be solved, but glob seems like it would make my code simpler, so I'd like to incorporate it.
For my original question though, could it be an issue with printing a list to a file that messes up the encoding?